# how to translate a dynamically added SVG animation on jointjs when a paper is scaled

Tags: svg, jointjs

I am not able to figure out how to re position an svg animation that i add dynamically on my paper during a zoom in or zoom out.

I add the animation when the link is active according to business logic in the following way.

```
  c = joint.V('circle', { r: 8, fill: 'green' });
      c.animateAlongPath({ dur: '4s', repeatCount: 'indefinite' }, canvasPaper.findViewByModel(link).$('.connection')[0]);
      joint.V(canvasPaper.svg).append(c)
```

Now i go to the canvas and zoom in or zoom out the elements in the canvas scale appropriately . i use the paper.scale command. But the animation that i added does not move. I was able to get it scaled down to size but not its position. How do i achieve this?.

My zoom in and zoom out code is as below. I also know that i have to use the translate command on the svg object but i do not know how to calculate the translate values based on the zoomLevel

```
  $('#zoom-in').on('click', function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          zoomLevel = Number((Math.min(1, zoomLevel + 0.2)).toFixed(1));
          canvasPaper.scale(zoomLevel, zoomLevel,0,0);  

_.each(canvasGraph.getLinks(), function(link) {
  if(link.attr('linkActiveAnimationSvgId/text')) {document.getElementById(link.attr('linkActiveAnimationSvgId/text')).setAttribute("transform", "scale(" + zoomLevel + "," + zoomLevel + ")")
  }
})

  })
```

My zoom out code is as below

```
  $('#zoom-out').on('click', function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
      zoomLevel =Number((Math.max(0.2, zoomLevel - 0.2)).toFixed(1));
    canvasPaper.scale(zoomLevel, zoomLevel,0,0);

_.each(canvasGraph.getLinks(), function(link) {
  if(link.attr('linkActiveAnimationSvgId/text')) {document.getElementById(link.attr('linkActiveAnimationSvgId/text')).setAttribute("transform", "scale(" + zoomLevel + "," + zoomLevel + ")")
  }
})

  })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok all i had to do was to find the view of the paper and then 
paperView.vel.append(c)
instead of
joint.V(canvasPaper.svg).append(c)
and now i scale the paper and the animation scales/translates appropriately